# Error: localhost redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, http-redirect

I have my framework set up as MVC type, where a core library redirects url. This is useful say if a link is as: `Some_class/some_method`, it will load *some_method* from *Some_class*. Also I have configured everything to pass through *index.php* using *.htaccess* file.
Code in **index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'config.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && empty($_GET['url'])) { ?>
    <a href="Users/login">Login</a><br>
    <a href="Users/register">Register</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Code in **config.php**

```
// Redirect to the homepage if not signed in
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
     header('location: http://localhost/index.php');
 }
```

Code in **Users** Controller

```
public function login(){
    // Code to verify the entered credentials
    // If entered data is valid
    $_session['user'] = $_POST['user'];
}
public function log_out(){
    session_unset();
}
```

If someone logs out using **log_out** method from **users** controller, the method executes. And if the code were right ideally it should redirect to *index.php*, because the code in *config.php* says that if `$_SESSION['user']` is not set, it should redirect to *index.php*. However, whenever someone logs out I get the error mentioned in the title. What mistake am I doing?

Comment: config.php checks a session var but you havent called `session_start` yet so it will never be set.  Also probably `exit` after redirect.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not fire up XDebug and set a breakpoint directly before the redirect happens?

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you have a redirect loop. This is what's happening.

1. User logs out and session is unset
2. User is then redirected to index.php where you call "config.php"
3. In config.php you check if the user is not logged in. He's not so it tells it to redirect to index.php (and you're back at point 2 again and round and round you go)

Change you config.php to redirect if the user IS logged in e.g.

```
// Redirect to the dashboard signed in
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
 header('location: http://localhost/dashboard.php');
}
```

Comment: the problem is actually I don't want anyone to go to any page without logging using url (let's take _dashboard.php_ . Other thing I can do is in _dashboard.php_, I can write if `(logged in?){execute code in dashboard.php}` . However there are many pages and I don't want to do that for every single page. So I want a if statement that would apply for any page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have session in your config.php... so do it like this..

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'config.php';
```

so your session will be in config.php too. Or take session_start() line to config.php, that could be better.

Comment: @tanadin Didn't help. Thank you by the way.

Comment: well everyone is saying same ;)

Comment: Honestly I tried it. Infact my original code has the identical code, it was here that I typed it this way.

Comment: I mean, that means you have another problem or something you cannot debug well.

Answer (score 0):

You have create whitelist of urls that should work without require user log in. For example, `$whitelist = ['Users/login', 'Users/register', '/'];` and check current url in redirect condition

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && !in_array($current_url, $whitelist)){
     header('location: http://localhost/index.php');
}
```

And `session_start()` issue from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You start your session after config.php is loaded. Otherwise the condition under the if statement will always be true and it will work as an infinite loop. Start the session first then load the config.php file. If your index.php file is for people who are not logged in, don't include the if block to check if user is logged in, when you load index.php. Because for guest users that will create same infinite loop. That part should be added to pages only for logged in users.